# Selecting common items from two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given two Sqlite databases:

1. db1 and db2 having "functions" table with almost 10k entries
2. There is a column "fcn_name" that will be conditioned
3. Both tables have 90% similar entries.

I need to SELECT `name and column2` from both tables HAVING same name and expected output is 90% of 10k but I get more than 10k entries as a result. In brief, I need an intersection for name column only but select name and column2 as a result.

I have tried the following sql statement:

`select count(*) from main.functions f, other.functions d where f.name=d.name`

`select distinct f.name from main.functions f, other.functions d where f.name=d.name`

Both do not work. Although with "distinct" keyword it returns fewer entries but still more than 10k. Why are there more entries?

Comment: If the `name` field is not unique, you generate a Carthian product for all duplicates. In that case, you will get more entries in total.

Comment: I'm lost.  If 90% of the rows have a name in common, then selecting all rows with common names would be 18,000 rows, not 9,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be caused by duplicates in both tables. Join both tables using DISTINCT names.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM main.functions) f1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM other.functions) f2 
ON f1.name = f2.name
```

Maybe that's the solution.

**Referring to your comment:**

If your tables have a primary key (e.g. an ID). So the following should deliver the desired result under sqllite:

```
SELECT f1.name, f1.yourField1, f1.yourField2, f1.yourField3 
FROM (SELECT name, yourField1, yourField2, yourField3
      FROM main.functions
      GROUP BY name
      HAVING id = MIN(id)
      ORDER BY id) f1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT name FROM other.functions) f2 
ON f1.name = f2.name
```

Comment: Right, this SQL statement gives the right number of common rows. But how can I extend it to select other columns after getting common rows? For example, I have another column "abc" and I want to select abc value from both rows with same name.

Comment: In this case you could use `GROUP BY`. For all other fields that you want to select, you would have to accept a restriction using aggregate functions such as `COUNT(), MAX(), MIN(), SUM(), AVG()`.

Answer (score 0):

To select rows that exist in both tables based on certain matching criteria, we'd typically use an INNER JOIN, e.g

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM main.functions f1 
INNER JOIN other.functions f1 
ON f1.name = f2.name
```

I'm not familiar with Sqlite, but would often be the approach with most DB's.

Comment: I have tried `INNER JOIN` but it return the similar results like `WHERE`. Somehow, results are same.

Comment: Are you saying `select distinct f.name from main.functions f` returns fewer rows then your second query?

Comment: ```select count(f1.name) from main.functions f1``` return 10k and similarly ```select count(f2.name) from other.functions f2``` return 10k But ```select count(distinct f1.name) from main.functions f1, other.functions f2 where f1.name=f2.name``` return 10.1k. However without distinct keywork it return 10.4k. The expected output is 9k approx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want all rows from one table where the name is in the other table.  For that, I would suggest:

```
select f.*
from main.functions f
where exists (select 1
              from other.functions o
              where o.name = f.name
             );
```

This does *not* check that the rows are the same, only that the name exists in both tables.  It also won't duplicate rows if there are multiple rows with the same name in both tables.

Comment: That's exactly what I am looking for but I need rows from both table. I need something like 
```select f1.name, f1.column2, f2.name, f2.column from main.functions f1, other.functions f2 where exists (select 1 from other.functions f2 where f1.name=f2.name)```